# Multipart File to File InputStream

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, file

How can I convert a `MultipartFile` to `FileInputStream` in memory?

I have tried to below , but i am facing the error as

> org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile cannot
>   be cast to java.io.File

My Code is

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream((File)file);
```

where file is a multipart file

Answer (score 33):

You can't create an instance of FileInputStream unless your file is not on file system.

You have to either first save the multipart file in temporary location on server using

```
file.transferTo(tempFile);
InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(tempFile);
```

But multipart file can also be read simply via basic streams methods such as

```
InputStream inputStream =  new BufferedInputStream(file.getInputStream());
```

Comment: i want to delete the temporary location as well at the end (including the contents and path)

Comment: @KaMaL - You can simply delete the file if you are 100% sure that you will not need this  in future. But a better approach will be the second one, accessing either directly via **InputStream** or a more efficient version via **BufferedInputStream**. This way you will be able to access the file in memory.

Comment: The file is not downloading if I directly take InputStream from URL.

Answer (score 4):

Try using:

```
MultipartFile uploadedFile = ((MultipartHttpServletRequest)request).getFile('file_name')
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(uploadedFile?.getBytes())
```

Answer (score 1):

Take look at [MultipartFile](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html)

In that you can go with :

```
void    transferTo(File dest)
```

This method transfer the received file to the given destination file.

Comment: file reading is done in inMemory so i cannot transfer to any destination

Answer (score 1):

```
MultipartFile file;
InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream();
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert Multipart file to Input Stream

```
MultipartFile file;
InputStream inputStream = new InputStream(file.getInputStream());
```

This worked for me.

Comment: InputStream cannot be instantiated.

Comment: InputStream showing error, it cannot be instantiated

Answer (score 0):

We may just cast and use like below

```
FileInputStream file = (FileInputStream) multipartFile.getInputStream();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  String filename = file.getOriginalFilename();
  Random val = new Random();
  int randomNumber = val.nextInt(999999);
  String filePath = path + File.separator + randomNumber+filename;
  file.transferTo(Paths.get(filePath));
```

**Note:** Generate the appropriate file-sending destination path and use the Multipartfile object file.transfterTo() method. its alternative of `copy()` the copy method makes me at runtime error, so the best way to copy and store your image use the file.transferTo() object.

Answer (score -2):

For a multipart file eg:

```
FileMultipartData part =  new FileMultipartData();
InputStream inputStream = part.getFileMultipart().get(0).getByteStream();
```

This worked for me in my code. Please try it